# How to Hide the second root of a tree

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on WPF `TreeView`, and I want to hide the parent of the tree.

My structure is `Main Root --> WSMethodName (2nd root) --> request and response sub children`

On my xaml  I can  hide `parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };` like this `ItemsSource="{Binding MessageElements[0].Children}"`.

How can I hide `wsMethodNameList`, which is the second root of the tree that contains request and response objects?

For this case the parent is:

```cs
var parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };
```

I populated my tree structure using this method:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel> GetAllTreeNodes()
{
    List<TreeViewModel> reqNodes = GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel();  // req
    //List<TreeViewModel> respNodes = GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel();  // res

    var request = new TreeViewModel();
    var response = new TreeViewModel();
    var parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };

    for (int i = 0; i < wsMethodNameList.Count; i++)
    {
        var child = new TreeViewModel { Value = wsMethodNameList[i] };
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        var requestChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = requestXmlList[i] };

        requestChild.Children = reqNodes;
        child.Children.Add(requestChild);

        var responseChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = responseXmlList[i] };
        responseChild.Children = reqNodes; // change to response nodes
        child.Children.Add(responseChild);
    }
    return new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> { parent};
```

xaml

```xml
<TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MessageElements,  Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MessageElementViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Children }">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Name}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

ViewModel

```cs
public ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel> MessageElements
{
    get { return messageElement; }
    set
    {
        if (messageElement == value)
            return;
        messageElement = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageElements");
    }
}
```

Loading data

```cs
public void LoadData()
{
    this.MessageElements = treeVModel.GetAllTreeNodes();
}
```

Comment: so u want the children listed but not the main root, is that right?

Comment: @dennisschütz yes just request and response children not their common root which is the WSMethodName.

Comment: already tried to use some linq operators to select the children?

Comment: show me the fields of ur model pls

Answer (score 0):

ok got to go. but if u can get all items of your model you can do something like this:

```
ChildrenList =   Model.GetAll().Where(c => c.Parent != null);
```

cant do more without more information. `Model.GetAll()` should contain every parent and every child of your collection and with my example you can fish out the children only. theoretically... :P
good luck